# How to line up ListView.builder and other widgets with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build a scrollable Flutter layout in which I have the following objects:

- One or more fixed height widgets
- A `ListView.builder()`

At the moment, I placed my layout in a `ListView` and the`ListView.builder()` height by setting `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

I noticed that the items in `ListView.builder()` are not getting disposed when I scroll through the list, probably because it's height is fixed and the list scrolls up and down as a solid layout.

I tried using a `NestedScrollView()`, but I noticed it's not meant to achieve what I want to do, that is columnating a widget with a `ListView.builder()` and keeping its disposing policy.

As far as I know, this is a problem about how am I creating the entire layout: I'm assuming that I have a fixed height scrollable: a "column" with widgets and `ListView.builder()` inside. Conceptually, I'd need a list which is builded dynamically inside a scrollable.

**P.S.**: I'm quite skilled as a Flutter developer, I can assure that there is nothing that prevents the `ListView.builder()` items to be disposed (I mean: keepalives, controllers, providers...). The point is that the list is not even attempting to dispose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to solve this problem by using a `SliverListView` inside a `CustomScrollView`, "translating" each widget of my original `Column` into their sliver's cousin.